# How to get the next/previous item from a spinner on button click?

Tags: android

I trying to implement something that looks like this.

[image]

The spinner contains a list of items that I fill using array adapter.

On button clicks I want to change the spinner's selected item to the next/previous item depending on whichever button is clicked. Is possible to do that? I'm using spinner because I've to fill a ListView above depending on the item selected in the spinner.

Can I use something else other than a spinner and buttons for this purpose?

Regards.

Comment: do you only want only date then no need to pass a list .Simply use calender object.In that case i Have a easy and quite small solution for your prob that exactly produces the results you want.

Comment: there is a default method for spinner which is setSelection(int position). you can use this method for your next and previous button.

Comment: I don't think I can use calendar,  because I'm getting getting those dates from a JSON.

Comment: @HeisenBerg then Strider's answer is good for u

Comment: Will the other spinner items be consecutive dates?or are they values defined by you like dates set 1 week apart?

Comment: They are not consecutive dates. They are random dates stored in list in decreasing order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is get the position of current item showing in spinner

and then in onclick event of back button 
this check is important cos if spinner showing element at zero and you press back button then poition will be -1; and will give exception.

```
 forward_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int position = mySpn.getSelectedItemPosition();
            if(position>0){
            position=position-1;
            mySpn.setSelection(position);

      }


        }
    });
 }
```

and in onclick event of forward button

below if check is important cos if your position is greater then size of your arraylist showing in spinner then it will also give exception.

```
previous_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                 int position = mySpn.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 if(position<your_list.size()){
                 position=position+1;
                 mySpn.setSelection(position);

             }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about -1. I've haven't started coding yet, but knowing this already will definitely save me a lot of time. Many thanks

Comment: possible bug: `position<your_list.size()` should be `position + 1<your_list.size()`?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
pirvate Spinner mySpinner;
private int ItemPosition;
private Button ButtonNext;
private Button ButtonPrevious;
```

in your `onResume()` :

```
ItemPosition = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

and your buttons:

```
ButtonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mySpinner.setSelection(mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(ItemPosition++));
    }
});

ButtonPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mySpinner.setSelection(mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(ItemPosition--));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Will the OnItemSelected() work when i change the item by button click?